# Able to install amazon app but not able to open it

Tags: java, selenium, mobile, appium

[image]with the help of apk file I am able to install the android app but it is not opening. Please see my code once:

```
package Test1;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Amazon_LogIn_Test {
private static AndroidDriver driver;

@BeforeMethod
@Test
public void setUp() throws Exception  {

File classpathRoot = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
File appDir = new File(classpathRoot, "/Apps/Amazon/");
File app = new File(appDir, "com.amazon.mShop.android.shopping-5.2.3-502030-  minAPI9.apk");

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "BECUPJTWGA7HAQQK");
capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "5");
capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.amazon.mShop.android.shopping");
capabilities.setCapability("appActivity",   "com.amazon.mShop.splashscreen.StartupActivity");

driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
Thread.sleep(10000);

    // Click on Shop by Deparment link
     driver.findElement(By.id("com.amazon.mShop.android.shopping:id/search_edit_text")).click();
    // Click on Main menu
    driver.findElementByClassName("android.widget.ImageView").click();
    // Click on Home link under Main menu
    driver.findElement(By.name("Home")).click();
    // Click on Sign In link on the Home Screen
    driver.findElementByName("Sign inHello. Link").click();

    Thread.sleep(10000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@content-desc='Hello. Sign in']"));

}
```

With the above code, I am able to install the amazon app and able to open the app as well but the last line which is there to click the sign in option is not getting clicked , i tried many way to do it.please help me on this.

Comment: this is because you are pointing to not current launching activity, you need mention launch activity in your DesiredCapabilities

Comment: Sorry didn't got you exactly

Answer (score 0):

Under desired capability instead of sign-in activity, please use splash activity, you need to change the activity in below line code:

```
capabilities.setCapability("appActivity","com.amazon.mShop.sso.SigninPromptActivity")
```

Comment: sorry i didn't get you exactly...can you please explain i am quite new on this

Comment: in the list of activities which appium shows, In app activity capability you are using sign-in activity i.e. "com.amazon.mShop.sso.SigninPromptActivity", in the list you can find splash activity, usually developer use splash activity to start the application.

Comment: how to get that splash activity , can you please help

Comment: May i kno how did you get SigninPromptActivity? so i can answer your question quickly.. and try the splash activity "com.amazon.mShop.splashscreen.StartupActivity"

Comment: Thanks for the help , now the app is opening but one more issue which i mentioned in the edited question, olease have a look once...Thanks

Comment: it seems you forgot to add click with this line of code  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@content-desc='Hello. Sign in']"))  it should be driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@content-desc='Hello. Sign in']")).click();

Comment: also you should ask a new question for new problems and accept the correct answers :)

Comment: Sorry i missed in posting, but click also i added but it is not working

Comment: are you able to locate this element using appium inspector? As it seems you have already clicked on sign-in link at "Sign inHello. Link" locator

Comment: i have use Ui  viewer for this ...Attaching the screen shot

Comment: this element you have displayed in image, is for full panel, you need to find out the exact element of sign-in/arrow button

Comment: Actually there is noting for it

Comment: as you can see in the node details section, this element is not clickable thats the reason you are unable to click it, so there must be some another node/element which is referenced to it and is clickable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this appActivity:

```
capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "in.amazon.mShop.android.shopping");
capabilities.setCapability("appActivity",   "com.amazon.mShop.splashscreen.StartupActivity");
```

i think your package name is wrong it should be "in.amazon.mShop.android.shopping" not this "com.amazon.mShop.android.shopping"

Comment: Thanks it worked but one more issue is it is not clicking the signin option

Comment: can you post the screenshot ?

Comment: thanks for quick response, actually you mention in above code for sign in locator & screenshot details are mismatched, better you can use resource id like this,
driver.findElementById("com.amazon.mShop.android.shopping:id/gw-mobile-greeting-bar").click();